# Wrong name displayed when i used the session that used in modal

Tags: php

my webpage displayed always the same name 
i need to display the name inside the modal that i clicked
this my code :

display the content(which is stored in mysql) if it's click the picture .

```
    <?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM pet where pet_cat = 'D' ORDER BY petid  ";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    $_SESSION['petname'] = $row['petname'];
    $_SESSION['petdesc'] = $row['petdesc'];
    $_SESSION['petimg'] = $row['petimg'];
    $_SESSION['petid'] = $row['petid'];

    echo '<li style="
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;">';
    echo '<a style= "cursor: pointer;"onclick= "document.getElementById(\'dogmod'.$row['petid'].'\').style.display=\'block\'">';
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($_SESSION['petimg'] ).'" />';
    echo '<h4>';
    echo $_SESSION['petname'] ;

    echo '</h4>';

    include 'desca.php';

    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}  

?>
```

the code of my modal
(desca.php)

```
   <div id="dogmod<?=$_SESSION['petid']?>" class="modal">

    <center>
        <form class="modal-content animate" style="margin: 0; padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px; padding-bottom:50px;">

            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('dogmod<?= $_SESSION['petid'] ?>').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close">&times;</span>
                <h1 align=center>Description</h1>

                <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($_SESSION['petimg'] ).'" style="margin-top:50px;float:left; margin-right:50px;"/>'; ?>
                <h1 style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px">
                    <?php echo $_SESSION['petname'] ;?>
                </h1>
                <p style="margin-bottom:50px;">
                    <?php  echo $_SESSION['petdesc'] ;?>
                </p>
                <input type="button" value="Back" onclick=location.href='doga.php' class="button_1" style="  width: auto;padding: 10px 18px; background-color: #f44336; border:0px; color:white;">

<input type="button" value="Adopt" onclick=location.href='form.php' class="button2"style= "  width: auto;padding: 10px 18px; background-color: #4CAF50; border:0px; color:white; ">

        </form>
    </center>

    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('dogmod');

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>

        </div>
```

and this is the form that i want to display the name.

```
   <div style="
    height: 70px;
">
                        <label>Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" style=" width: 100%;
                            padding: 0px 10px;
                            width:323px;
                            text-align:center;
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            border: none;
                            border-bottom: 1px solid;" placeholder="Name" value="<?=$_SESSION['fullname']?>" name="fname">

                            <label>Age:</label>
                            <input type="text"style=" width: 100%;
                            padding: 0px 20px;
                            width:100px;
                            text-align:center;
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            border: none;
                            border-bottom: 1px solid;"  placeholder="Age" name= "age">

                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" style=" width: 100%;
                            padding: 0px 20px;
                            text-align:center;
                            width:298px;
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            border: none;
                            border-bottom: 1px solid ;"  value = "<?=$_SESSION['email']?>" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <div style="
    height: 70px;
">
                            <label>Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" style=" width: 100%;
                            padding: 0px 20px;
                            width:795px;
                            text-align:center;
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            border: none;
                            border-bottom: 1px solid;"  placeholder="Address" name="adrs">
                            </div >
                            <div style="
    height: 70px;
">
                            <label>Mobile Number:</label>
                            <input type="text" style=" width: 100%;
                            padding: 0px 20px;
                            text-align:center;
                            width:300px;
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            border: none;
                            border-bottom: 1px solid ;" value = "<?=$_SESSION['contactnum']?>" placeholder="Contact Number" name="mnum"><br>
                            </div>
                            <div style="
    height: 70px;
">
                            <label>Name/Description of animal:</label>
                            <input type="text" style=" width: 100%;
                            padding: 0px 20px;
                            text-align:center;
                            width:220px;
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            border: none;
                            border-bottom: 1px solid ;" value = "<?=$_SESSION['petname']?>" placeholder="petname" name="petname">
                        </div>
```

() i used this code to display name that the same name in the modal but unfortunately this will display always the same wrong name.

Comment: Please, post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), show, which result you get, and which you expect. It is unclear, what is exactly your problem.

Comment: my problem is i used $_SESSION['petname'], when i click the picture then the modal popup, each modal has different details. but when i click the adopt in the modal the petname always display the same wrong name

Comment: Well. Do you generate your code for modal only once? (I mean. not inside the loop). If so, the problem is next: you overwrite `$_SESSION['petname']` on each loop iteration and it will always contain last petname.

Comment: i don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your loop you overwrite `$_SESSION["petname"]` (as well, as some other values), so it always will store only the last petname. If I understand clearly you want next: user clicks the *adopt*-button after what he is redirected to the page with a form. In that form you want to see correct petname. Here is one possible solution:

Modify your *adopt*-button, set:

```
onclick=location.href='form.php?petname=<?=$_SESSION['petname']; ?>'
```

And in your modal modify input with petname, set:

```
value = "<?=$_GET['petname']?>"
```

I hope this will work. But you should think about improving you algorithm. You don't really need `$_SESSION` to store pet-information here. Also, maybe you would like to leave those modal on the same page and fill it with js.

Answer (score 0):

like @Alex Yokisama Said

> "The problem is that in your loop you overwrite $_SESSION["petname"]
>   (as well, as some other values)"

i suggest you should use AJAX, just like this !!

```
<?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM pet where pet_cat = 'D' ORDER BY petid  ";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    $petname = $row['petname'];
    $petdesc = $row['petdesc'];
    $petimg  = $row['petimg'];
    $petid = $row['petid'];

    //echo '<li style="
    //padding-right: 20px;
    //padding-left: 20px;">';
   // echo "<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm" data-id=" $petid;" id="formPet"></a> ";
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($petimg).'" />';
    // echo '<h4>';
    // echo $_SESSION['petname'] ;
    // echo '</h4>';
    //include 'desca.php';

    //echo '</a>';
    //echo '</li>';

    ?>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm" data-id="<?php echo $petid; ?>" id="formPet">FormOpen</button>

    <?php 
}  

?>
```

//button click ajax script

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).on('click', '#formPet', function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var uid = $(this).data('id'); // it will get id of clicked row

                    $('#form-content').html(''); // leave it blank before ajax call
                    $('#formmodal-loader').show(); // load ajax loader

                    $.ajax({
                            url: 'form.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: 'id=' + uid,
                            dataType: 'html'
                        })
                        .done(function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#form-content').html('');
                            $('#form-content').html(data); // load response 
                            $('#formmodal-loader').hide(); // hide ajax loader 
                        })
                        .fail(function() {
                            $('#form-content').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Something went wrong, Please try again...');
                            $('#formmodal-loader').hide();
                        });

                });
});                
</script>
```

//This modal will execute once you click at-least 1 button in the while loop

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h5 class="modal-title w-100 font-bold">PET MODAL</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-3">

                <div id="formmodal-loader" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
                    <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif">
                </div>

                <!-- content will be load here -->
                <div id="form-content"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//create a file name form.php and get the requested id from your ajax post

```
<?php 
require_once('dbconfig.php');
if (isset($_REQUEST['id']) ){

    $pet_id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    //create a form or view content here base on the id of pet you want to add/edit/delete/view

    }
```